# OctoberCMS Register users by group

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller, octobercms-widgets

I would like during registration the user can choose a group, and register users by to their group

for example at registration there are 2 groups, "freelancer" and "employer"

Thank you for your help

Comment: can you confirm you need this at front-end side.

Comment: **Yes exactly!!!**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this with the existing user plugin Account component.
Mostly because it uses Auth::register() to save the new user and there is no relation saving there.

You could create your own component that extends the account component and from your own form call onRegisterPlus() function.

```
public function onRegisterPlus()
{
    $this->onRegister();// call the accout component onRegister method

    /** You may want to do some verification here that this
        is a new registraion to prevent submitting existing
        email and changing the groups.
        or not use $this->onRegister() and just copy it to
        your own method and modify to fit your needs.
    */

    if($user= User::where('email',post('email'))->first()){
        $user->groups()->sync(post('groups'))
    }
}
```

You would make your form as mentioned and include checkboxes named 'groups[]' with the value of the groups you want available.